# Another way to Encrypt App.config Connection String in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, encryption

I know there are a lot of SO posts regarding this question but most of the answers are suggesting to use `aspnet_regiis`, my problem is that you need to be on the same server or network so that you can connect to the server and it should always be run in Administrator privilege.

So I'm thinking if there are other built-in class in `.NET` that I can use to encrypt or can I program it?

Comment: Ultimately, any encryption you use has to be reversible (with methods to reverse it being right there in your code) to be usable within your application.

Comment: @CoolBots so do you know other Encryption tools?

Comment: What is your *threat model*? Encryption doesn't magically fix things - who are you trying to hide this information from?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I will distribute it to other users

Answer (score 0):

Please look into following article hope this is what you are looking for..

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598863/EncryptionplusDecryptionplusConnectionplusStringpl

Comment: It will only be encrypted if I run the program?